# Errors when using webpack with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, mern

I'm working through the examples in Pro MERN Stack by Apress and have hit on an issue with webpack. Up until I started using it, everything worked as expected. Now when I run `npm run compile` I get this:

```
> pro-mern-stack@1.0.0 compile /Users/me/Documents/Books/Pro MERN Stack/pro-mern-stack
> webpack

Hash: 3869c18532e36184fca8
Version: webpack 4.12.0
Time: 1101ms
Built at: 2018-06-16 18:56:00
 1 asset
 [0] ./src/BorderWrap.jsx 2.33 KiB {0} [built]
 [2] ./src/IssueList.jsx 6.38 KiB {0} [built]
 [3] ./src/IssueFilter.jsx 2.25 KiB {0} [built]
 [4] ./src/IssueAdd.jsx 3.03 KiB {0} [built]
[17] ./src/App.jsx 882 bytes {0} [built]
    + 13 hidden modules

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/me/Documents/Books/Pro MERN Stack/pro-mern-stack/node_modules/react-dom/cjs'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js 13:53-69
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./src/App.jsx

ERROR in ./src/App.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/me/Documents/Books/Pro MERN Stack/pro-mern-stack/src'
 @ ./src/App.jsx 3:13-29

ERROR in ./src/IssueList.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/me/Documents/Books/Pro MERN Stack/pro-mern-stack/src'
 @ ./src/IssueList.jsx 9:13-29
 @ ./src/App.jsx

ERROR in ./src/BorderWrap.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/me/Documents/Books/Pro MERN Stack/pro-mern-stack/src'
 @ ./src/BorderWrap.jsx 9:13-29
 @ ./src/App.jsx

ERROR in ./src/IssueFilter.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/me/Documents/Books/Pro MERN Stack/pro-mern-stack/src'
 @ ./src/IssueFilter.jsx 9:13-29
 @ ./src/App.jsx

ERROR in ./src/IssueAdd.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/me/Documents/Books/Pro MERN Stack/pro-mern-stack/src'
 @ ./src/IssueAdd.jsx 9:13-29
 @ ./src/App.jsx
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! pro-mern-stack@1.0.0 compile: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pro-mern-stack@1.0.0 compile script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-06-16T17_56_00_932Z-debug.log
```

I don't believe anything has changed with react so can't understand why it would suddenly cause issues. My thinking is that there is either something wrong with webpack or the version of webpack I'm using does not work with the version of react. I assume its the same issue for each error.

Has anybody expreienced anything similar and if so how did you resolve it?

**Adding package.json**

```
{
  "name": "pro-mern-stack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon -w server.js server/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "co": "^4.6.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.7",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json file. It seems react is not installed for the project.

Comment: @tarzenchugh I've added to my question. Thanks.

Comment: please use - 'npm i react' 
to install react into your application, I only see react-dom being installed.

Comment: Ah, that works now. I'm just thinking. I had been using `<script src=
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.js">
  </script>` in my index.html but removed it. Obviously forgot to install react. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @tarzenchug, react was not installed. When I ran `npm i react` it worked.